# Why does Camtasia Studio Recorder sometimes zoom in during my screencasts?

Tags: screen-recorder, camstudio

E.g. in http://youtu.be/qGTNDKxREH0 at second 22 Camtasia Studio Recorder decided to zoom in. How can I prevent it from doing so? I use Camtasia Studio Recorder 7.0.0 + Win7 SP1 x64.

Comment: Does this still happen?

Comment: I haven't seen it since I switched to Camtasia Studio Recorder 8

Comment: But I am still curious for my laptop with Camtasia Studio Recorder 7.